# Can't see CSS menu in Internet Explorer 8 (potential javascript issue?)

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8

I keep getting complaints about this menu bar not functioning correctly in Internet Explorer 8.  I have absolutely NO CLUE what is wrong with this code since it works on all other browsers, as well as earlier versions of IE.

Here is the website:

http://www.iirusa.com/centrallab

You can see the CSS here:
http://www.iirusa.com/ed/4999/css/main.css

And here is my code for the menu:

```
    <script src="/upload/wysiwyg/AC_RunActiveContent.js" type="text/javascript>
    </script>
    <DIV id="header"><a href="/centrallab/home-page.xml"><img src="http://www.iirusa.com/upload/wysiwyg/2011-P-Div/P1625/P1625_Central_Labs_East.jpg" alt="Central Labs East" width="930" height="206" border="0" /></a></DIV>
    <DIV id="container">
    <ul id="nav">
    <li style="background: url(http://www.iirusa.com/upload/wysiwyg/2011-P-Div/P1625/P1625_menu_item_image.gif) no-repeat right center;"><a href="/centrallab/home-page.xml" title="HOME">HOME</a></li>
    <li style="background: url(http://www.iirusa.com/upload/wysiwyg/2011-P-Div/P1625/P1625_menu_item_image.gif) no-repeat right center;"><a href="#">EVENT DETAILS</a> 
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/centrallab/agenda-page.xml" title="Agenda At A Glance">Agenda At A Glance</a></li>
        <li><a href="/centrallab/workshop-page.xml" title="Monday Sessions">Monday Sessions</a></li>
        <li><a href="/centrallab/oncology-page.xml" title="Oncology Summit">Oncology Summit</a></li>
        <li><a href="/centrallab/speakers.xml" title="Speakers">Speakers</a></li>
        <li><a href="/centrallab/Whowillyoumeet.xml" title="Who You Will Meet">Who You Will Meet</a></li>
        <li><a href="/centrallab/attendees-page.xml" title="Attendees List">Attendees List</a></li>
        <li><a href="/centrallab/pricing-venue.xml" title="Pricing & Venue">Pricing & Venue</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>

    <li style="background: url(http://www.iirusa.com/upload/wysiwyg/2011-P-Div/P1625/P1625_menu_item_image.gif) no-repeat right center;"><a href="#">PARTNERS</a> 
     <ul>
        <li><a href="/centrallab/sponsors-page.xml" title="Sponsors">Sponsors</a></li>
        <li><a href="/centrallab/exhibitors.xml" title="Exhibitors">Exhibitors</a></li>
        <li><a href="/centrallab/become-a-sponsor.xml" title="Become a Sponsor">Become a Sponsor </a></li>
        <li><a href="/centrallab/become-a-exhibitors.xml" title="Become an Exhibitor">Become an Exhibitor </a></li>
        <li><a href="/centrallab/become-a-media-partner.xml" title="Become a Media Partner">Become a Media Partner</a></li>
   </ul>
   </li>
 <li style="background: url(http://www.iirusa.com/upload/wysiwyg/2011-P-Div/P1625/P1625_menu_item_image.gif) no-repeat right center;"><a href="/centrallab/brochure-download.xml" title="Brochure">BROCHURE</a> </li>
 <li style="background: url(http://www.iirusa.com/upload/wysiwyg/2011-P-Div/P1625/P1625_menu_item_image.gif) no-repeat right center;"><a href="">REGISTRATION </a>
    <ul><li><a href="/centrallab/registration-LP.xml" title="Register">REGISTER </a></li>
      <li><a href="/centrallab/pricing-venue.xml" title="Pricing & Venue">Pricing & Venue</a></li>
      </ul></li>
      <li style="background: url(http://www.iirusa.com/upload/wysiwyg/2011-P-Div/P1625/P1625_menu_item_image.gif) no-repeat right center;"><a href="#">CONNECT</a>
      <ul>
      <li><a href="/centrallab/contact-page.xml" title="Contact Us">Contact Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="/centrallab/opt-in-page.xml" title="Opt-in">Opt-in</a></li>
      <li><a href="/centrallab/send_to_friend.xml" title="Send to a Friend">Send to a Friend</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/groupRegistration?gid=151146&amp;goback=.gdr_1219853769141_1.anb_151146_*2" title="LinkedIn" target="_blank">LinkedIn</a></li>
     <li><a href="http://partnershipswithcros.blogspot.com/" title="Blog" target="_blank">Blog</a></li>
     <li><a href="http://twitter.com/partnershipcros?utm_source=sidebar&amp;utm_medium=croshomepage&amp;utm_term=croshomepage&amp;utm_content=followcros&amp;utm_campaign=homepage" title="Twitter" target="_blank">Twitter</a></li>
     <li><a href="http://labroots.com/?appinstanceid=groups&amp;action=view&amp;id=150" title="Labroots" target="_blank">Labroots</a></li>
    </ul></li>
   </ul>
 </DIV>
```

The only other issue I can think of is that there is something wrong with the JS we are referencing which can be found here: http://www.iirusa.com/upload/wysiwyg/AC_RunActiveContent.js

Please let me know if you can help! Would be very appreciated and would make hours of frustration worth it!!

Comment: And sorry I forgot to mention that the main "functionality" problem is that you cannot hover over the links in the horizontal menu bar to view the sub-menu pull down links

Comment: No problem at all in IE8 for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its IE6 not IE8. The problem is that IE6 does not support the `:hover` selector on anything besides and `a` tag

Answer (score 2):

On my IE8 installation your website doesn't work if IE8 is in Compatibility View.

Make sure that the browser does not go into the Compatibility View by adding this to your `head`:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Menus work perfectly when IE8 is not in CV.